# Getting value of input element in Playwright

Tags: playwright

How do I return the value of elem so that I can verify that it is in fact `1`?

```js
const elem = await page.$('input#my-input')
await elem.fill('1')
```

Comment: *See this* http://stackoverflow.com/a/76106077

Comment: The accepted answer was updated from the above original answer which is below in the same post.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Also, since v1.20 there's the `toHaveValue` matcher that can verify an element's value:

```js
await expect(page.locator('input#my-input')).toHaveValue('1');
```

`inputValue` method has been added in Playwright v1.13.0

```js
await page.inputValue('input#my-input');
```

Locator:

```js
await page.locator('input#my-input').inputValue();
```

It returns `input.value` for the selected `<input>` or `<textarea>` element. Throws for non-input elements. [Read more](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-input-value).

Meanwhile, if you want to assert the value you can use [toHaveValue](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-value)

```js
const locator = page.locator('input#my-input');

await expect(locator).toHaveValue(/[0-9]/);
```

Comment: Better than `$eval()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

The easiest way is to use [`$eval`](https://playwright.dev/#version=v1.0.2&path=docs%2Fapi.md&q=pageevalselector-pagefunction-arg). Here you see a small example:

```js
const playwright = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  const browser = await playwright.chromium.launch();
  const context = await browser.newContext();
  const page = await context.newPage();
  await page.setContent(`<input id="foo"/>`);
  await page.type("#foo", "New value")
  console.log(await page.$eval("#foo", el => el.value))
  await page.screenshot({ path: `example.png` });
  await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: Thanks Max. I'm looking for an easy way to check the value of an HTML element handle. Is this possible?

Comment: Note for others: The essential code you're looking for is `await page.$eval("#foo", el => el.value)`.

Comment: Note also that [`$eval()` doesn't perform actionability checks](https://playwright.dev/docs/actionability) (it doesn't autowait), so you might need to precede your `$eval()` with something like `await page.waitForSelector("#foo")`

Comment: in case of having issues with type, you can set:
`el as HTMLInputElement;`

Answer (score 5):

From version 1.19 (and probably lower versions) Element Handler is not recomended.
Instead of it use Locator.

```
page.locator(selector).innerText()
```

in your case with assertion it will be

```
expect(page.locator("input#my-input").innerText().includes("1")).toBeTruthy()
```

Read more on:
https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#element-handle-fill

Answer (score 2):

Use [toHaveValue](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-value) to get and verify value at same time.

```
await expect(locator).toHaveValue('1')
```

It ensures the Locator points to an element with the given input value. You can use regular expressions for the value as well.

Reference: https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locatorassertions#locator-assertions-to-have-value

https://stackoverflow.com/a/73138411/1831456
[Getting value of input element in Playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62002041)

Answer (score 0):

This is to get the value through chrome context ( like executing in chrome devtools console  )
.
.
As per the latest document it can be achieved using `page.evaluate`
.
https://playwright.dev/docs/evaluating
.

#### Example

.

```js
const linkhrefFromBrowser = await page.evaluate(async () => {
    // The below instructions will run in the browser console ( context )
    let element = element.getElementById("pagelink");
    let linkhref = element.getAttribute("href");
    console.log(linkhref); // will be printed in browser tab
    return linkhref; // whatever you return will be available in linkhrefFromBrowser variable
  });
```