# getting input value and matching using playwright test runner

Tags: playwright

Using `await page.inputValue('input')` to get the input value and it returns the actual value but how do i test for it?

I have tried something like this `await expect(page.inputValue('input')).toHaveValue('10');` but that does not work.

Comment: You probably want to `await page...`. But "does not work" is an unclear problem statement. What leads to you believe it doesn't work? Was there an error or specific behavior? Please share it and provide a [mcve]. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use this:

```js
await expect(page.locator('input')).toHaveValue('10')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```js
const value = await page.inputValue('input');
expect(value).toEqual('10')
```

or shorter

```js
expect(await page.inputValue('input')).toEqual('10')
```