# I can't get input element value in my playwright e2e test

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, playwright

This is the input tag that I want to get date value

```html
<input readonly="" name="issued_at" type="text" placeholder=" " id="issued_at" data-testid="issued_at--input" autocomplete="new-textBox" value="5/3/2023">
```

I need to get the date value in this tag.

I wrote this function for getting the value but it didn't worked for me

```
async daysBetweenDates() {
    const issueDateBox = await this.page.$('input#issued_at');
    const issueDateText = await issueDateBox.getAttribute('value');
    console.log(issueDateText);
}
```

I got this error:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getAttribute')

Any idea?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probaably the element not yet available in the page DOM at that point

Comment: No, I put a wait also. It has no effect.

Answer (score 1):

##### How to get input value in playwright?

Use `Locator inputValue` to get input value.

```
const value = await this.page.locator('input#').inputValue();
```

And the text value can be verified with `toHaveValue` :

```
const locator = page.locator('input#');
await expect(locator).toHaveValue('SomeText');
```

Reference:https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-input-value

[Getting value of input element in Playwright](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62002041/getting-value-of-input-element-in-playwright)

Comment: I tried inputValue() and textContent() before, but neither worked.

Comment: That was not mentioned in the question ,also the code shared was not even using locator earlier which is the best practice now.